# Grouping of inner Maps with Java Streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

i have following structure:

```
Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>>
```

Now i want to disregard the First-level-Maps and group (and sum up) the 3rd-Level-Maps according to the key of the 2nd-Level-Maps.
To Clarify some example-Entries:

```
Entry 1: ["1"["A"[[a,1];[b,2]];"B"[[a,3];[c,1]]]]
Entry 2: ["2"["A"[[b,2];[c,1]];"B"[[a,5];[b,0]]]]
```

Desired output:

```
Entry 1: ["A"[[a,1];[b,4];[c,1]]]
Entry 4: ["B"[[a,8];[b,0];[c,1]]]
```

So to do this I first group my Entry-stream according to my 2nd-Level-Keys ("A","B") and, if nothing else done, end up with a structure like the following:

```
Map<String,List<Entry<String,Map<String,Integer>>>>
```

And here is where I am stuck. How do i go about getting my `Map<String,Integer>`from my List of Entries (for each outer Map, secifically)?

The simple code which I assume is guaranteed to be needed:

```
        initialMap.values().stream()
                            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey));
```

Summary:

How do I transform a `Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>>` to a `Map<String<Map<String,Integer>>`, disregarding the outermost `Map`, grouping my innermost `Maps` according to my 2nd-Layer-`Keys` and summing my `Integer`-values by `key`-values of the Innermost `Map`. 
Additionally the outermost `Maps` each have a `Key-Value-Pair` for each 2nd-Level-`Map`, so each will have the same 2nd-Level-`Keys`. In the 3rd-Level-`Keyset`s can be `Keys` not found in other 3rd-Level-`Maps`

Comment: for summing up i would recommend the usage of `.reduce`

Comment: It's hard to keep context from external iteration in streams. Why not just iterate without them then?

Comment: Pretty much learning purposes...i am currently getting used to the stream-api and havent worked extensivly with it yet. Such scenarios are pretty much a gateway for me to understand the whole thing further. If there is no real way (or only a very hard one) i am glad as well, cause that means i dont overlook sth obvious, but if there is a way to do it with streams i would certainly be interested on how to, cause i couldnt solve it and was trying to for quite some time^^

Comment: You seem to use maps to store only one entry in each one : `Entry 1: ["1"["A"[a,1]]]` Do use consider that these maps are SingletonMap (a map with a single entry)  ?  I ask you the question because otherwise your input-output in your question is too simple. For example, which expected for this input :  `["1"["A"[a,1], "B"[a,1]]]` ?

Comment: @Proph3cy, you can do this with streams, but it's not particularly nice to do, and isn't really intended for such uses.

Comment: How can you have duplicate keys in the map. For an instance you have key 1, three times in the map which is not possible.

Comment: ok, I was a bit unprecise with my examples...will edit them

Comment: Problems regarding the examples should be solved now.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov OK, that's sth I can get behind. Will do it with Iteration for now. Would still be interested in how sth like it can be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thing to keep in mind here: streams conceptually represent a single element coming down through a "pipe" of sorts. It's always single element when the stream runs, no matter if source has one, multiple or infinite number of elements backed up in total.

What you're trying to do here is represent several nested loops, along the lines of:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> firstMap : inputMap.values()) {
    for (Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> firstEntry : firstMap.entrySet()) {
        String upperCaseKey = firstEntry.getKey();
        Map<String, Ingeter> resultEntry = result.computeIfAbsent(
            upperCaseKey,
            _k -> new HashMap<>());
        for (Entry<String, Integer> secondEntry : firstEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {

            resultEntry.merge(secondEntry.getKey(), secondEntry.getValue(), Integer::sum);

        }
    }
}
```

Among the better ways to do it with streams would be via `Collector` composition:

```
inputMap.values().stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())

    .flatMap(firstEntry -> firstEntry.getValue()
                           .entrySet().stream()
                           .map(secondEntry -> new SimpleImmutableEntry(
                                                       firstEntry.getKey(),
                                                       secondEntry)
                           )
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
          compositeEntry -> compositeEntry.getValue().getKey(),
          Collectors.summingInt(compositeEntry -> compositeEntry.getValue().getValue())
        )
    ));
```

That should do the trick in general, but note how I had to first build up a composite entry, to keep element count as 1, and then nested two grouping collectors. This is why I'm of the opinion that tasks like yours aren't good fit for the API. It's also very likely to require a little help from you to compiler, as it may struggle to infer all the types correctly.

Also note, that this is not the only way to do it: the Stream API is very flexible, and you're likely to see many more other ways to do the same.

Comment: ok, thanks for sharing that whole thing^^ Will stick to the iteration-based solution as u sugested (for readability), but is still a huge help to see how to go about sth like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> result = 
    initialMap
        .values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                       Collectors.groupingBy(e -> mapToFirstEntry(e.getValue()).getKey(), 
                                                             Collectors.summingInt(e -> mapToFirstEntry(e.getValue()).getValue()))));
```

but it assumes that a third-level `Map<String, Integer>` contains one entry and there is a method to get that entry:

```
public static Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapToFirstEntry(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    return map.entrySet().iterator().next();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the liberty of using Java9, I would suggest you to use the `flatMapping` collector to solve this problem. This approach is much more readable and generates less visual clutter to me. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> summaryMap = map.values().stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)))));
```

This program produces the following output:

> {A={a=1, b=4, c=1}, B={a=8, b=0, c=1}}